# Canvas app scroll bar - no "settable" option

Tags: facebook, canvas, scroll

I have posted this bug report on the Facebook developers hub but (as usual with Facebook support) the staff have given a quick answer which doesn't actually address my real question at all. The bug report is at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/109891925817737. See this link for all the details.

The short version is that in all the canvas documentation (e.g. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/), there is a height option called "settable" which you can use with the "setAutoGrow" to ensure the Facebook canvas frame always resizes to the size of your application. If you don't use this, you get a weird double vertical scroll bar which makes the app really hard to use.

Problem is, the "settable" option doesn't actually exist in the app settings. The Facebook staff member said this is now the "designed work flow". Well, that's fine, but the real question still remains - how do I remove the double vertical scroll bars? I have tried both the available settings in the new "work flow", but neither of them work with the "setAutoGrow" on.

Does anyone know how to set this up? Are there any examples of documentation around how this new "work flow" should be considered to solve the double scroll bar issue?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation to FB.setAutoGrow says it would only work when "canvas height" is set to "fixed (800px)", but I found that not to be the case, with set to "fluid" it seems to work as well.

If it’s not working for you with either setting, I’m guessing your doing something wrong – like not proberly initializing the SDK first.